# Set Interval in Node.js vs. Cron Job?

Tags: node.js, cron

I'm learning node.js and just set up an empty Linux Virtual Machine and installed node.

I'm running a function constantly every minute

```
var request = require('request')
var minutes = 1, the_interval = minutes * 60 * 1000

setInterval(function() {
    // Run code
  })
}, the_interval);
```

And considering adding some other functions based on current time. - (e.g. run function if dateTime = Sunday at noon)

My question is are there any disadvantages to running a set up like this compared to a traditional cron job set up?

Keep in mind I have to run this function in node every minute anyways.

Comment: i can't comment for now (les reputations) [here](https://serverfault.com/a/854096) is a fair comparison

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It depends on how strictly you have to adhere to that minute interval and if your node script is doing anything else in the meantime. If the *only* thing the script does is run something every X, I would strongly consider just having your node script do X instead, and scheduling it using the appropriate operating system scheduler.

If you build and run this in node, you have to manage the lifecycle of the app and make sure it's running, recover from crashes, etc. Just executing once a minute via CRON is much more straightforward and in my opinion conforms more to the [Unix Philosophy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#McIlroy:_A_Quarter_Century_of_Unix).

Comment: Looking back on this now I feel CRON is the superior solution. Why should I run a node app 24/7 when I could simply setup a cron-job to run for the few seconds each day that I need it to.

Comment: but isn't cron an app that runs 24/7 ?

Answer (score 40):

> My question is are there any disadvantages to running a set up like this compared to a traditional cron job set up?

As long as `//run the code` isn't a CPU-bound thing like cryptography, stick with 1 node process, at least to start. Since you are requiring `request` I guess you might be making an HTTP request, which is IO, which means this will be fine.

It's just simpler to have 1 thing to install/launch/start/stop/upgrade/connect-a-debugger than to deal with an app server as well as a separate cron-managed process. For what it's worth, keeping it in javascript makes it portable across platforms, although that probably doesn't really matter.

There is also a handy [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) module which I have used as well as approximately one bazillion other alternatives.

Comment: Peter: Do you run node-cron on the same node instance as your other stuff?  I am considering doing something similar but am curious if spinning up another instance is a good idea...

Comment: Yes, start simply and have one process. It's easier to monitor, keep running, and debug initially. As your operational capability and traffic load increases, later split it off into a separate process, but KISS to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Cron, unless your app is really small and simple.

Also, the in-memory setTimeout would not work if you ever end up behind a load balancer.  You might have two+ instances of your node server running and thus your function/script running multiple times instead of once.