# How to make a server hosted script run at a certain hour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I have a script where I update some things to a Shopify shop, however, it works only when I press a button, using a server router:

```
router.post('/sync_shopify_with_set/:id', TokenController.isAValidToken, async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await ShopifyController.syncShopifyWithSetState(req.params.id);
        res.json({
            success: true
        });
        console.log('Shopify updated');
    } catch (error) {
        ErrorController.errorCallback(error, res);
    }
});
```

How can I make it so than, whenever the clock strikes 12 at night (CST), the `await ShopifyController.syncShopifyWithSetState(req.params.id)` function executes automatically? (Wether via a router or another way).

This code is all hosted in my server.

Comment: Use a cron job.

Comment: @Bergi care to elaborate?

Comment: Use cron for this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you implement periodically executing job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830002/how-do-you-implement-periodically-executing-job)