# Getting notifications when an object is posted on an auction site

Tags: php, time, screen-scraping

I'm trying to program something that will look up a few search queries on an auction site every hour or so and send a notification to me (email for example) when a new object is posted that matches the search query. I'm trying to do this for this site: http://www.2dehands.be/

The point is , this site has no API. How do I handle this? I've looked into web scraping but that doesn't look real time. I have knowledge about Ruby, Javascript, HTMl/CSS, Python and a bit of mysql and php. How can I best accomplish my goal?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems like they got an [RSS Feed](http://www.2dehands.be/doc/rss.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A simple PHP solution

There are many different ways you could go about doing something along the lines of what you are asking, but I would suggest a simple php script that runs your desired queries on your database and if a result is found then send an email using the built in php email function.

Once you have created this script you can have it run as a Cron Job (this is a popular script job application used on linux servers) every hour or however often you would prefer.

*Keep in mind you can use any type of script job running application to run your scripts if you don't have CronJob available.

If this is unclear let me know. This is just one of many ways, but using PHP for these types of tasks is ideal if you are comfortable with PHP and need to run server side scripts.

Comment: I have never used php to actually look for information in a web page, (I just know the syntax structure from codecademy.) Do you have any tutorials on this stuff you can recommend? Also I have never used a cronjob before. Is it kind of the same as doing this in nodejs?

Comment: You can use something like mysqli when running queries on your db and when you want to send email follow this php documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php.

Comment: @Thijs for more reference on cron jobs and node.js see this stackoverflow answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120909/set-interval-in-node-js-vs-cron-job or for a detailed breakdown of what a cron job is within linux check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron