# setInterval right away then wait 5 seconds

Tags: node.js, express, request, consul

I am building a Node.js application and I have a `setInterval` function that runs every 5 seconds. My issue is the this function has to run before any of my routes will work in that file.

I need to run the setInterval right away upon my application starting but then run every 5 seconds after that.

So far I have tried setting the setInterval to a lower amount but that puts too much stress on my external service since this code format will be used in a bunch of files (~30).

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const config = require("../config/config");

const request = require("request");
var consul = require("consul")({host: '10.0.1.248'});
var consulBase = [];
var options;


setInterval(() => {
  consul.catalog.service.nodes('auth', function(err, results) {
    if(err) {console.log(err); throw err;}
    if(results.length <= 0) throw 'Unable to find any services with that name.. exiting process...';
    if(results.length > 0) consulBase = [];
    results.forEach((result) => {
      consulBase.push(result.ServiceAddress+ ':' +result.ServicePort);
    });
    var serviceURL = 'http://' + consulBase[Math.floor(Math.random()*consulBase.length)];
    options = {
      baseUrl : serviceURL
    };
  });
}, 5 * 1000);

router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  request.get(req.path, options, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) throw error;
    res.send(body);
  });
});


module.exports = router;
```

I'd be open to putting this in a different file and then having it present itself as a function that takes a service name and gives out an `options` variable with the data I need. Not sure how I would do that though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at scheduled tasks for node, using a package like [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron). For example the following code will run every 5 seconds

```
var cron = require('node-cron');

yourCode();

cron.schedule('*/5 * * * * *', () => {
  yourCode();
});


function yourCode(){
  console.log('running every 5 seconds');
}
```

Without node-cron

```
yourCode();

setInterval(() => {
  yourCode();
}, 5 * 1000);


function yourCode (){
  console.log('running every 5 seconds');
}
```

In seperate files

```
//code.js
module.exports.yourCode= (req, res) =>{
    console.log('running every 5 seconds');
}

//app.js
const yourCode = require ('./code').yourCode;

yourCode();

setInterval(() => {
  yourCode ();
}, 5 * 1000);
```

Comment: My code will run every 5 seconds, perfectly fine too. Issue is getting it to run right away and adding another dependency is not ideal.

Comment: you then want to run your code without the setInterval at start up and copy your code inside the scheduler. And without some scheduling tool it's not possible for you to run your task every 5 seconds, without writing a similar code yourself like you have

Comment: > And without some scheduling tool it's not possible for you to run your task every 5 seconds

You mean that setInterval doesn't work for that? Seems to work fine how I have it for running every 5 seconds.

Comment: sorry mistook for setTimeout, but node-cron basically does the same as well but better for more reasons, for info (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120909/set-interval-in-node-js-vs-cron-job)

Comment: I know of node-cron and others like it, I don't want to include them unless needed because I see no advantage from it. Literally all I need is a simple set interval and I need to run my code before setInterval starts. Heck it even takes more lines of code to get the same result.

Comment: Without node-cron it's still pretty much the same. Hope the update helps

Comment: How could I put that in a different file? Would it just be `exports.yourCode = () => {//login}` then `var yourCode = require('./path/to/yourCode') yourCode.yourCode()`

Comment: would appreciate if you mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: Ops sorry thought I did should be now

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `setInterval` in a simple method that calls the function in argument, then creates the interval and returns the interval ID.

```
let intervalId = executeAndRepeat(function(){
    //do your thing
    if(someCondition)
        return clearInterval(intervalId);
}, 5 * 1000);

function executeAndRepeat(fcn, intervalTime){
    fcn();
    return setInterval(fcn, intervalTime);
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that.  Also, how could I do it so that the function is in a different file so I don't have to repeat this process for every file?

Comment: I'm trying to understand how this is any better than what I have, it still has the same issue of only running after 5 seconds and not right away then after 5 seconds.

Comment: It does not. It runs immediately, then every 5 seconds after the first execution ended.
It is pretty straight forward code really.