# Is it appropriate to use setInterval to perform repeated tasks? (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, task, setinterval

I want to execute a repeated task in **every two** hours in a Node JS app.

Is it efficient to use `setInterval(function() {...}, 7200000)` to do this or is it suggested to use maybe a module to achieve the same thing?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron

Comment: It's not appropriate though, check out [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) on npm, it can do a lot a that stuff and it's easy to learn :)

Comment: read this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120909/set-interval-in-node-js-vs-cron-job. It