# How to update the node js Date() function daily without restarting my server daily

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I am currently using the node Date() function to track days for a scheduling website I am creating, however, to get to the next day it requires me to stop and restart the server each time. How can I continually ping it so it updates itself?

Comment: call `new Date()` again?

Comment: Without knowing anything about how you're doing things now, you might consider a [cron job](https://scotch.io/tutorials/nodejs-cron-jobs-by-examples).

Comment: I used a cron job they are very simple and powerful thank you

Answer (score 0):

In theory, each invocation of the `Date()` function should return the current date and time. I just tested this in node v13.13.0 over midnight, and it worked perfectly fine.

Are you calling `Date()` once upon server startup and then storing that value in a variable?

If you need to call an update function at midnight, you could use:

```
function dailyUpdate() { console.log(new Date()) }

midnight               = new Date().getTime()
millisecondsToMidnight = (
    midnight 
  - new Date().getTime() 
  + midnight.getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000
)

setTimeout(() => {
  dailyUpdate();
  setInterval(() => {
    dailyUpdate()
  }, 24*60*60*1000)
}, millisecondsToMidnight)
```

Comment: Using setInterval is not a good way to go about running something that you want to run at a precise time, especially if the host observes daylight saving. A cron job is likely a much better option, see [*Set Interval in Node.js vs. Cron Job?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120909/set-interval-in-node-js-vs-cron-job)